# How to continue variable data respectively?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I create a analog clock away from the traditional method.
It have 30 hours

12 seconds = 1 minute
12 minutes = 1 hour

'Second-hand' need to complete one circle by 12 steps.
when 'Second-hand' complete one circle then, 'minute-hand' need to move one step.
like that 'minute-hand' need to complete a circle by 12 steps too.
When 'minute-hand' complete one circle then, hour circle need to move one step.
In this way 'hour-hand' need to complete entire circle'by 30 steps.

But in this program its unable to move 'minute-hand' properly.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const hourHand = document.querySelector("[data-hour-hand]");
  const minuteHand = document.querySelector("[data-minute-hand]");
  const secondHand = document.querySelector("[data-second-hand]");

  let totalMilliseconds = 0;
  let previousSecond = 0;
  let secondsCounter = 0;

  function updateClock() {
    // Calculate Sinhala time with 12 minutes per hour
    const sinhalaHours = Math.floor(totalMilliseconds / (30 * 60 * 12 * 1000));
    const remainingMilliseconds = totalMilliseconds % (30 * 60 * 12 * 1000);
    const sinhalaMinutes = Math.floor(remainingMilliseconds / (60 * 12 * 1000));
    const sinhalaSeconds = Math.floor((remainingMilliseconds % (60 * 12 * 1000)) / 1000);

    // Check if a new second circle has started
    if (sinhalaSeconds < previousSecond) {
      // Increment minute only when a new second circle starts
      sinhalaMinutes++;
      // Reset the seconds counter
      secondsCounter = 0;
    }

    // Calculate degrees for each hand
    const hourDeg = (sinhalaHours + sinhalaMinutes / 60) * 360 / 30;
    const minuteDeg = (sinhalaMinutes + sinhalaSeconds % 12) * 360 / 12; // Adjust for 12 steps
    const secondDeg = (sinhalaSeconds % 12) * 360 / 12; // Adjust for 12 steps

    // Apply rotations to the clock hands
    hourHand.style.transform = `rotate(${hourDeg}deg)`;
    minuteHand.style.transform = `rotate(${minuteDeg}deg)`;
    secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondDeg}deg)`;

    // Update the previous second and seconds counter
    previousSecond = sinhalaSeconds;
    secondsCounter++;
  }

  // Update the total milliseconds and the clock every 1000 milliseconds (1 second)
  setInterval(function () {
    totalMilliseconds += 1000;
    updateClock();
  }, 1000);

  // Initial call to set the clock when the page loads
  updateClock();
});
```

```css
*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Gotham Rounded, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, hsl(200, 100%, 50%), hsl(175, 100%, 50%));
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.clock {
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.clock .number {
  --rotation: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotate(var(--rotation));
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.clock .number1 { --rotation: 12deg; }
.clock .number2 { --rotation: 24deg; }
.clock .number3 { --rotation: 36deg; }
.clock .number4 { --rotation: 48deg; }
.clock .number5 { --rotation: 60deg; }
.clock .number6 { --rotation: 72deg; }
.clock .number7 { --rotation: 84deg; }
.clock .number8 { --rotation: 96deg; }
.clock .number9 { --rotation: 108deg; }
.clock .number10 { --rotation: 120deg; }
.clock .number11 { --rotation: 132deg; }
.clock .number12 { --rotation: 144deg; }
.clock .number13 { --rotation: 156deg; }
.clock .number14 { --rotation: 168deg; }
.clock .number15 { --rotation: 180deg; }
.clock .number16 { --rotation: 192deg; }
.clock .number17 { --rotation: 204deg; }
.clock .number18 { --rotation: 216deg; }
.clock .number19 { --rotation: 228deg; }
.clock .number20 { --rotation: 240deg; }
.clock .number21 { --rotation: 252deg; }
.clock .number22 { --rotation: 264deg; }
.clock .number23 { --rotation: 276deg; }
.clock .number24 { --rotation: 288deg; }
.clock .number25 { --rotation: 300deg; }
.clock .number26 { --rotation: 312deg; }
.clock .number27 { --rotation: 324deg; }
.clock .number28 { --rotation: 336deg; }
.clock .number29 { --rotation: 348deg; }
.clock .number30 { --rotation: 360deg; }

.clock .hand {
  --rotation: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  z-index: 10;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(calc(var(--rotation) * 1deg));
}

.clock::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 11;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.clock .hand.second {
  width: 3px;
  height: 45%;
  background-color: red;
}

.clock .hand.minute {
  width: 7px;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: #443f3f;
}

.clock .hand.hour {
  width: 10px;
  height: 35%;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>
  <title>Clock</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="clock">
    <div class="hand hour" data-hour-hand></div>
    <div class="hand minute" data-minute-hand></div>
    <div class="hand second" data-second-hand></div>

    <div class="number number1">1</div>
    <div class="number number2">2</div>
    <div class="number number3">3</div>
    <div class="number number4">4</div>
    <div class="number number5">5</div>
    <div class="number number6">6</div>
    <div class="number number7">7</div>
    <div class="number number8">8</div>
    <div class="number number9">9</div>
    <div class="number number10">10</div>
    <div class="number number11">11</div>
    <div class="number number12">12</div>
    <div class="number number13">13</div>
    <div class="number number14">14</div>
    <div class="number number15">15</div>
    <div class="number number16">16</div>
    <div class="number number17">17</div>
    <div class="number number18">18</div>
    <div class="number number19">19</div>
    <div class="number number20">20</div>
    <div class="number number21">21</div>
    <div class="number number22">22</div>
    <div class="number number23">23</div>
    <div class="number number24">24</div>
    <div class="number number25">25</div>
    <div class="number number26">26</div>
    <div class="number number27">27</div>
    <div class="number number28">28</div>
    <div class="number number29">29</div>
    <div class="number number30">30</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you over-complicate the issue. You want a clock that runs 12 times faster. Simply use timestamps to calculate the passed time and multiply that by 12.

Comment: Sorry sir, I am new to javascript. can you edit the source code ?

Comment: @sonny Hour hand not working properly !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const hourHand = document.querySelector("[data-hour-hand]");
  const minuteHand = document.querySelector("[data-minute-hand]");
  const secondHand = document.querySelector("[data-second-hand]");

  let totalMilliseconds = 0;
  let previousSecond = 0;
  let secondsCounter = 0;

  function updateClock() {
    // Calculate Sinhala time with 12 minutes per hour
    const sinhalaHours = Math.floor(totalMilliseconds / (30 * 60 * 12 * 1000));
    const remainingMilliseconds = totalMilliseconds % (30 * 60 * 12 * 1000);
    const sinhalaMinutes = Math.floor(remainingMilliseconds / (60 * 12 * 1000));
    const sinhalaSeconds = Math.floor((remainingMilliseconds % (60 * 12 * 1000)) / 1000);

    

    

    // Calculate degrees for each hand
    const minutes = (sinhalaSeconds / 12); //calculate minutes, changed %12 to /12 
    const hours = (sinhalaSeconds / 12 /12); //calculate hours

    const hourDeg = Math.floor(hours)* 360 / 30;
    const minuteDeg = Math.floor(minutes) * 360 / 12; // Adjust for 12 steps. Math.floor activates the TICKING effect because it updates only on full minutes. 
    const secondDeg = (sinhalaSeconds % 12) * 360 / 12; // Adjust for 12 steps

    // Apply rotations to the clock hands
    hourHand.style.transform = `rotate(${hourDeg}deg)`;
    minuteHand.style.transform = `rotate(${minuteDeg}deg)`;
    secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondDeg}deg)`;

    // Update the previous second and seconds counter
    previousSecond = sinhalaSeconds;
    secondsCounter++;
  }

  // Update the total milliseconds and the clock every 1000 milliseconds (1 second)
  setInterval(function () {
    totalMilliseconds += 1000;
    updateClock();
  }, 100);

  // Initial call to set the clock when the page loads
  updateClock();
});
```

```css
*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Gotham Rounded, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, hsl(200, 100%, 50%), hsl(175, 100%, 50%));
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.clock {
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.clock .number {
  --rotation: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotate(var(--rotation));
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.clock .number1 { --rotation: 12deg; }
.clock .number2 { --rotation: 24deg; }
.clock .number3 { --rotation: 36deg; }
.clock .number4 { --rotation: 48deg; }
.clock .number5 { --rotation: 60deg; }
.clock .number6 { --rotation: 72deg; }
.clock .number7 { --rotation: 84deg; }
.clock .number8 { --rotation: 96deg; }
.clock .number9 { --rotation: 108deg; }
.clock .number10 { --rotation: 120deg; }
.clock .number11 { --rotation: 132deg; }
.clock .number12 { --rotation: 144deg; }
.clock .number13 { --rotation: 156deg; }
.clock .number14 { --rotation: 168deg; }
.clock .number15 { --rotation: 180deg; }
.clock .number16 { --rotation: 192deg; }
.clock .number17 { --rotation: 204deg; }
.clock .number18 { --rotation: 216deg; }
.clock .number19 { --rotation: 228deg; }
.clock .number20 { --rotation: 240deg; }
.clock .number21 { --rotation: 252deg; }
.clock .number22 { --rotation: 264deg; }
.clock .number23 { --rotation: 276deg; }
.clock .number24 { --rotation: 288deg; }
.clock .number25 { --rotation: 300deg; }
.clock .number26 { --rotation: 312deg; }
.clock .number27 { --rotation: 324deg; }
.clock .number28 { --rotation: 336deg; }
.clock .number29 { --rotation: 348deg; }
.clock .number30 { --rotation: 360deg; }

.clock .hand {
  --rotation: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  z-index: 10;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(calc(var(--rotation) * 1deg));
}

.clock::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 11;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.clock .hand.second {
  width: 3px;
  height: 45%;
  background-color: red;
}

.clock .hand.minute {
  width: 7px;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: #443f3f;
}

.clock .hand.hour {
  width: 10px;
  height: 35%;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>
  <title>Clock</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="clock">
    <div class="hand hour" data-hour-hand></div>
    <div class="hand minute" data-minute-hand></div>
    <div class="hand second" data-second-hand></div>

    <div class="number number1">1</div>
    <div class="number number2">2</div>
    <div class="number number3">3</div>
    <div class="number number4">4</div>
    <div class="number number5">5</div>
    <div class="number number6">6</div>
    <div class="number number7">7</div>
    <div class="number number8">8</div>
    <div class="number number9">9</div>
    <div class="number number10">10</div>
    <div class="number number11">11</div>
    <div class="number number12">12</div>
    <div class="number number13">13</div>
    <div class="number number14">14</div>
    <div class="number number15">15</div>
    <div class="number number16">16</div>
    <div class="number number17">17</div>
    <div class="number number18">18</div>
    <div class="number number19">19</div>
    <div class="number number20">20</div>
    <div class="number number21">21</div>
    <div class="number number22">22</div>
    <div class="number number23">23</div>
    <div class="number number24">24</div>
    <div class="number number25">25</div>
    <div class="number number26">26</div>
    <div class="number number27">27</div>
    <div class="number number28">28</div>
    <div class="number number29">29</div>
    <div class="number number30">30</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

For testing purpose I have made the clock fast, change it. remove the Math.floor part to remove the ticking effect and move the minutes a little bit hand every second

Answer (score 0):

There is mistake in minuteDeg calculation. Correct way is:

```
const minuteDeg = (sinhalaMinutes + sinhalaSeconds / 144) * 360;
```

Check the result:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const hourHand = document.querySelector("[data-hour-hand]");
  const minuteHand = document.querySelector("[data-minute-hand]");
  const secondHand = document.querySelector("[data-second-hand]");

  let totalMilliseconds = 0;
  let previousSecond = 0;
  let secondsCounter = 0;

  function updateClock() {
    // Calculate Sinhala time with 12 minutes per hour
    const sinhalaHours = Math.floor(totalMilliseconds / (30 * 60 * 12 * 1000));
    const remainingMilliseconds = totalMilliseconds % (30 * 60 * 12 * 1000);
    const sinhalaMinutes = Math.floor(remainingMilliseconds / (60 * 12 * 1000));
    const sinhalaSeconds = Math.floor((remainingMilliseconds % (60 * 12 * 1000)) / 1000);

    // Check if a new second circle has started
    if (sinhalaSeconds < previousSecond) {
      // Increment minute only when a new second circle starts
      sinhalaMinutes++;
      // Reset the seconds counter
      secondsCounter = 0;
    }

    // Calculate degrees for each hand
    const hourDeg = (sinhalaHours + sinhalaMinutes / 60) * 360 / 30;
    const minuteDeg = (sinhalaMinutes + sinhalaSeconds / 144) * 360; // Adjust for 12 steps
    const secondDeg = (sinhalaSeconds % 12) * 360 / 12; // Adjust for 12 steps

    // Apply rotations to the clock hands
    hourHand.style.transform = `rotate(${hourDeg}deg)`;
    minuteHand.style.transform = `rotate(${minuteDeg}deg)`;
    secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondDeg}deg)`;

    // Update the previous second and seconds counter
    previousSecond = sinhalaSeconds;
    secondsCounter++;
  }

  // Update the total milliseconds and the clock every 1000 milliseconds (1 second)
  setInterval(function () {
    totalMilliseconds += 1000;
    updateClock();
  }, 1000);

  // Initial call to set the clock when the page loads
  updateClock();
});
```

```css
*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Gotham Rounded, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, hsl(200, 100%, 50%), hsl(175, 100%, 50%));
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.clock {
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.clock .number {
  --rotation: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotate(var(--rotation));
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.clock .number1 { --rotation: 12deg; }
.clock .number2 { --rotation: 24deg; }
.clock .number3 { --rotation: 36deg; }
.clock .number4 { --rotation: 48deg; }
.clock .number5 { --rotation: 60deg; }
.clock .number6 { --rotation: 72deg; }
.clock .number7 { --rotation: 84deg; }
.clock .number8 { --rotation: 96deg; }
.clock .number9 { --rotation: 108deg; }
.clock .number10 { --rotation: 120deg; }
.clock .number11 { --rotation: 132deg; }
.clock .number12 { --rotation: 144deg; }
.clock .number13 { --rotation: 156deg; }
.clock .number14 { --rotation: 168deg; }
.clock .number15 { --rotation: 180deg; }
.clock .number16 { --rotation: 192deg; }
.clock .number17 { --rotation: 204deg; }
.clock .number18 { --rotation: 216deg; }
.clock .number19 { --rotation: 228deg; }
.clock .number20 { --rotation: 240deg; }
.clock .number21 { --rotation: 252deg; }
.clock .number22 { --rotation: 264deg; }
.clock .number23 { --rotation: 276deg; }
.clock .number24 { --rotation: 288deg; }
.clock .number25 { --rotation: 300deg; }
.clock .number26 { --rotation: 312deg; }
.clock .number27 { --rotation: 324deg; }
.clock .number28 { --rotation: 336deg; }
.clock .number29 { --rotation: 348deg; }
.clock .number30 { --rotation: 360deg; }

.clock .hand {
  --rotation: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  z-index: 10;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(calc(var(--rotation) * 1deg));
}

.clock::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 11;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.clock .hand.second {
  width: 3px;
  height: 45%;
  background-color: red;
}

.clock .hand.minute {
  width: 7px;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: #443f3f;
}

.clock .hand.hour {
  width: 10px;
  height: 35%;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>
  <title>Clock</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="clock">
    <div class="hand hour" data-hour-hand></div>
    <div class="hand minute" data-minute-hand></div>
    <div class="hand second" data-second-hand></div>

    <div class="number number1">1</div>
    <div class="number number2">2</div>
    <div class="number number3">3</div>
    <div class="number number4">4</div>
    <div class="number number5">5</div>
    <div class="number number6">6</div>
    <div class="number number7">7</div>
    <div class="number number8">8</div>
    <div class="number number9">9</div>
    <div class="number number10">10</div>
    <div class="number number11">11</div>
    <div class="number number12">12</div>
    <div class="number number13">13</div>
    <div class="number number14">14</div>
    <div class="number number15">15</div>
    <div class="number number16">16</div>
    <div class="number number17">17</div>
    <div class="number number18">18</div>
    <div class="number number19">19</div>
    <div class="number number20">20</div>
    <div class="number number21">21</div>
    <div class="number number22">22</div>
    <div class="number number23">23</div>
    <div class="number number24">24</div>
    <div class="number number25">25</div>
    <div class="number number26">26</div>
    <div class="number number27">27</div>
    <div class="number number28">28</div>
    <div class="number number29">29</div>
    <div class="number number30">30</div>
  </div>
</body>
```